# Expressing the width of a div next to floated elements in terms of free space

Tags: css, css-float, width, percentage

In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vmTJ/) I want to express `.four` div's width as a percentage of the remaining screen space and not the total screen width. But as the preceding three divs in the hierarchy are floated this is currently not happening.

What do I need to do to be able to define `.four`'s width in terms of remaining horizontal screen space?

Answer (score 2):

just remove the width from  this class `.four` it will automatically cover up the remaining space.
and give `margin-left`the total of `three div's` value than `fourth div` will start after three div's

**CSS**

```
.four{
background-color:black;
color:white;
margin-left:360px;    
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3vmTJ/6/)

Comment: this does not allow me to define .four in terms of the remaining space - applying a percentage width will still be in terms of the whole screen unless I'm missing something?

Comment: you are missing something because i have made the demo as per your requirement check it your code properly where you doing something wrong or show us where you are applying this thing...

Comment: You are missing something - specifically - *I want to express .four div's width as a percentage of the remaining screen space and not the total screen width.* Your solution does not allow me to express that div's width in terms of remaining screen space.

Comment: *as a percentage of the remaining screen space* - so, when I define width:60%; I want it to be 60% of the width of (the body less the 3 floated divs) and not 60% of the body as it is currently.

Comment: You ignored me in chat so I'll repost here - You are not addressing the problem I described.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you will have to wrap it in a parent element that takes up 100% of the remaining width so that you can make .four a percentage of that.

To get the parent element to take up the remaining space, well, it ain't pretty, but your best bet may be to resort to the table display styles.  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kBmbk/12/)

**Markup**

```
<div class="menu-outer-outer">
    <div class="menu-outer">       
        <div class="menu one">first</div>
        <div class="menu two">second</div>
        <div class="menu three">third</div>
        <div class="four-container">
            <div class="four">helloworld</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.menu-outer-outer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu-outer {
    display: table-row;
}
.menu{
    display: table-cell;
    height:240px;
    width:120px;
}
.one{
    background-color:red;
}
.two{
    background-color:blue;
}
.three{
    background-color:green;
}
.four-container {
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
}
.four {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Comment: How do I get 100% of remaining width though? If I apply width:100% it will be 100% of screen width.

Comment: Just updated with a way to do it, using the table display styles

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning is one solution, but you may have issues once the screen size becomes smaller.
http://jsfiddle.net/kudoslabs/HMydq/

```
.four{
background-color:black;
color:white;
position: absolute;
left: 360px ;
right: 0;   
}
```